# My blur filter doesn't seem to working correctly, even though if I test it using sample pictures they are blurred

Tags: c, rgb, cs50

Currently I am doing a computer course in which I have to write a blur filter for .BMG images.
The filter loads the pictures correctly, and creates new ones based on my filter.

I have tested the blur filter using sample pictures, and it seems to work (to my eye).

However the course has an auto grader in which I can see that my results differ.

Here is a link to my results, scroll all the way down to see the results for the blurr function:
https://submit.cs50.io/check50/73d0a0da48b323a1a8e306fc0ef528cd2df269c3

Here is the code that I wrote to solve this problem:

```
// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{

    RGBTRIPLE TEMP[height][width];
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            TEMP[i][j].rgbtRed = image[i][j].rgbtRed;
            TEMP[i][j].rgbtGreen = image[i][j].rgbtGreen;
            TEMP[i][j].rgbtBlue = image[i][j].rgbtBlue;
        }
    }

    // this  forloop will read in the height
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {

        // this forloop will read in the with
        for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            float count = 0;
            float red = 0;
            float green = 0;
            float blue= 0;

            // this forloop will loop three times, for the average filter
            for(int q = -1; q < 2; q++)
            {
                // this forloop will loop three times, making the total 9 for each pixel
                for(int w = -1; w < 2; w++)
                {
                    // this if statement makes sure that the I stay within the pixel I J array
                    if(w >= 0 && w < width && q >= 0 && q < height)
                    {
                        red += TEMP[i+q][j+w].rgbtRed;
                        green += TEMP[i+q][j+w].rgbtGreen;
                        blue += TEMP[i+q][j+w].rgbtBlue;
                        count ++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
            // this should set the [i][j] value of each colour to the average of the values
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = round(red/count);
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round(green/count);
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round(blue/count);
        }

    }
}
```

Hopefully someone can help me with my mistake.

Comment: You change `image[i][j]` before you calculate the new `image[i+1][j]` that seems problematic.

Comment: Pretty sure you want `< 2`, not `<= 2` in your loops. And you don't need `else { continue; }` because there's nothing else for the loop to do. It will "continue" by default when it reaches the closing brace `}`.

Comment: `< width` and `< height` as well instead of `<=`. You should read from the source image and write to a new image then copy the new to source after all the processing has been done. You also want to move red, green, blue, and count into the `j < width` loop. They need to reset for every pixel.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. I updated the code, I copied ``image[i][j]`` to ``TEMP[I][J]``. So calculating with that will won't interfere with the values of ``image[i][j]``  also moved red green and blue within the j loop. I have edited the main question with these changes. As well as new results which are slightly bettter.

Comment: Change all `float` to `int`

Comment: `if(w >= 0 && w < width && q >= 0 && q < height)` is incorrect. You need to calculate the pixel position `i + q` and `j + w` and use those to clip against the edges instead of `w` and `q`.

Comment: @RetiredNinja that makes a lot of sense! I'll give it a shot, I also changed the floats to integers.

Comment: Pretty sure you'll still want to do the average as a floating point calculation with `round`. It'll be pretty obvious, you'll be off by 1 in some cases.

Comment: @RetiredNinja you are right, i should keep the floats. The solution works now. And I also understand why for the most past. The only thing I don't fully grasp is this: ``if((j+w) >= 0 && (j+w) < width && (q+i) >= 0 && (q+i) < height)``. Why should it be < width and < height, instead of =< width and =< height. This would seem to me that it skippes the highest row and the highest height.

Comment: Indices are 0 based. So for a row with 10 pixels the valid indices are 0 .. 9. Since the pixel values are whole numbers then adding them up as floats or ints should be the same. I'd likely use ints and then cast `count` to a float when dividing.

Comment: That makes a lot sense. Thanks!